# Regex to find a string in python

Tags: python, regex

**Input**

```
text = "Store Item Number (DPCI)=244-02-6685;Pop Musical Style=Arena Rock, Album Rock, Pop-Metal, Hard Rock, Hair Metal, Heavy Metal;Origin=Made in the USA or Imported;Record label=UNIVERSAL INT'L;...."
```

**Output**

```
(Store Item Number (DPCI),Pop Musical Style, Origin, Record label)
```

I need a regex for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/xEHiWf/1) an example of this:

```
^[^=]+|(?<=;)[^=]+
```

Which finds elements in between `;` and `=`, or the one that starts on the beginning of the input and ends with a `=`.

Output: `['Store Item Number (DPCI)', 'Pop Musical Style', 'Origin', 'Record label']`

Answer (score 0):

`\w+` will match any word, but you are trying to match specific strings.

```
(Store Item Number \(DPCI\)|Pop Musical Style|Origin|Record label)\=
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookbehinds to grab the data after `Store Item Number (DPCI)` and `Pop Musical Style`:

```
import re
text = "Store Item Number (DPCI)=244-02-6685;Pop Musical Style=Arena Rock, Album Rock, Pop-Metal, Hard Rock, Hair Metal, Heavy Metal;Origin=Made in the USA or Imported;Record label=UNIVERSAL INT'L;"
data = re.findall('(?<=Store Item Number \(DPCI\)\=)[\d\-]+|(?<=Pop Musical Style\=)[a-zA-Z\s,]+', text)
```

Output:

```
['244-02-6685', 'Arena Rock, Album Rock, Pop']
```